# Ruby on Rails: is using params.require() important?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm trying to create a RESTful API for a very simple web app I made using Ruby on Rails. Specifically, I'm trying to implement the `POST /users.json` to create a new user.

The "*parsing the response to JSON*" bit is handled by the scaffolding. The issue comes when trying to use the strong parameters method scaffolded.

I make a POST request using the Postman Chrome extension to:

```
   # POST /users
   # POST /users.json
   def create
     user_params[:karma] = 1
     @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So `user_params` is called, and it **requires** a user (note that this method was generated by the scaffolding):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :karma, :about)
end
```

I realised I can work this around by simply "*not requiring*" the user in params:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:name, :karma, :about)
end
```

But is this safe or appropriate? Is there a more correct way?

And why is the **user** even required in the first place, if that's exactly what I intend to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :karma, :about)
```

Says that the params hash MUST contain a key called user and checks that associated value only contains the named keys. Aside from this security check, it returns pretty much what `params[:user]`. This requires that the params hash is of the form

```
{
  :user => {
    :name => "Bob",
    :about => "Professional builder",
    :karma => "10"
  }
}
```

You'll get a parameters hash like this if the field names in the form / http request are `user[name]`, `user[about]`, which is exactly what you'll get if you use the rails form helpers

On the other hand it sounds like the parameters hash your sending is

```
{
  :name => "Bob",
  :about => "Professional builder",
  :karma => "10"
}
```

because in your request the field names are `name`, `about`, `karma`.

The problem with doing `params.permit(:name, :karma, :about)` is that it stops you from ever passing other parameters to the action because the parameter checker won't allow them (and if you did allow them then User.new would complain).

Comment: Thank you. Your response helped me find my error. I kept the _require_ and I realised my error was triggered by me not passing a properly formatted JSON object... *sighs*